# How to make the key.click() repeatedly work?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to make an autoclicker, but it's currently only clicking once when I press a random key that isn't `esc`.

```
import keyboard
import time
import pyautogui as key
time.sleep(4)
Count=0
while True:
    
    key.click()
    print('Click')
    Count=Count+1
    if keyboard.read_key()=='esc':
        print("Quit!", Count)
        break
```

Comment: It might be stopping and waiting for a keyboard input on each loop. Try `import keyboard; help(keyboard.read_key)` in an interactive session and see what it says.

Comment: Count=Count+1 works i guess, but start using Count += 1 this adds every time you loop through 1 to your variable Count.

Comment: Use `keyboard.is_pressed`, it detects if a key is pressed one time and should be used in the loop. I'll add an answer in a second

Answer (score 0):

The below code will keep clicking till a key (esc) is pressed:

```
from keyboard import is_pressed as isp
from pyautogui import click
from time import sleep

sleep(4)
count = 0
while not isp('esc'):
    click()
    print('clicky')
    count += 1
print('\nDone! Times clicked:\t', count)
```

If you want to do it only **when** a key is pressed:

```
from keyboard import is_pressed as isp
from pyautogui import click
from time import sleep

sleep(4)
count = 0
while not isp('esc'):
    if isp('some key'):
        click()
        print('clicky')
        count += 1
print('\nDone! Times clicked:\t', count)
```

Also don't **EVER** use `while True` with pyautogui, it's especially dangerous. Unless you know to trigger the failsafe, you basically can't stop if the break statement goes wrong. Take it from someone who has made that mistake.

Comment: Thanks!I'll make to keep your advice!

Comment: @Wise.Snowy Also, is there any specific reason you were using `keyboard.read_key()` over `keyboard.is_pressed()`?